# How to get GMT offset from candle in the past MQL4

Tags: date, datetime, timezone-offset, mql4, metatrader4

It is actually an MQL4 question.

What I actually need to code is an indicator, which draws a vertical line on the day the timezone of the broker has been changed. This is happening once on every 6 month.

Any idea how to get the GMT offset of a candle in the past or anything similar ?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

`int TimeGMTOffset()` and `datetime TimeGMT()` are available in MQL4, but you cannot know what was a GMT offset some time ago as the `TimeGMT()` returns the same value for any bar.

Comment: it seems the broker sets the time of this parameter from their end.

Answer (score 0):

### Long story short:

Based on what was available in 2017Q3, there is the only chance for MQL4-code to ask an external process.

### Doable:

The external process ( be it a python, **`tz`**-equipped, code or other ) must be informed not only of the Bar's "indicated"-time, from `iTime(...)`, but it must also have gotten be configured, where is the Trading-Server located ( the Broker-specific setup ) + whether all the Broker-Servers keep their geo-located-TimeZone or still keep some Broker's administrative-centre "united" TimeZone-location, even if not physically present in such administratively-given-TimeZone location.

I.e. London access-point may present itself to be in UTC +0000 geo-location zone, but yet may follow UTC { +0300 | +0400 }-administratively-enforced-TimeZone location(s).

The same applies for what rules do actually enforce the Broker's Server DLS-Time { On | Off }-to happen in reality. US geo-located Broker's Servers may yet be subordinated for non-US DLS-Time shift dates.

So, indeed, not an easy or any straightforward step to ask today, what was the actual geolocated time in some far moment of time in the past.